# Jquery problems with some chars in strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm having troubles with some string chars like `'c++'`, when trying manipulating that i receive an `error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: +`

Is there some way of declaring strings or somenthing more that can be usefull to this case?

In this case i pass var `k = 'c++'` to a function which prints that var in this way:

```
$('#wrapper').html('<span>'+k+'</span>');
```

Comment: post more code - the error is not in what you posted so far

Comment: I think we need to see your EXACT code as this works for me: http://jsbin.com/opison/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you eval'ing the above code?  As it stands what you have there works fine if it's just included in a page with var k = "c++".

If you are going to eval the string, then you should surround 'k' with quotes and also escape any quotes that might be in it.

Comment: the example above is not ok, i do many other operations with var k; :P

Comment: is here some method to define string type?

Comment: No, there's only one type of string in JavaScript. I agree with the other guys that there's some kind of usage of the code that's causing your problem that isn't written above.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks fine. Runs with no problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbM6P/)

That is not the line of code causing the error

Comment: the example above is not ok, i do many other operations with var k; :P , but i can't post all my functions here, too much code

Comment: is here some method to define string type?

Comment: The code posted above runs without a problem (see the JS fiddle link). To diagnose the problem we really need to see the code that is generating the error. Have you tried using  Firebug to identify the line of code throwing the exception?

Comment: yep i'm using firebug, i definitly fixed using not strings but integers for now :P